# How to map OVER(PARTITION BY) data with Dapper

Tags: c#, sql-server, orm, dapper

I am using the following SQL query to get a list of Configurations and with each Configuration, the latest Instance sorted by Date DESC.

```
SELECT
  Configurations.*,
  inst.*
FROM (
    SELECT
      Instances.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Configurations.ID
                   ORDER BY Instances.CreateDate DESC) AS [Row Number]
    FROM Configurations
    INNER JOIN Instances on Instances.ConfigurationID = Configurations.ID
) inst
INNER JOIN Configurations ON Configurations.Id = inst.ConfigurationId
WHERE inst.[Row Number] = 1
```

My Configuration Model looks like this:

```
[ExplicitKey] public int Id { get; set; }        
public string Name { get; set; } = "";
//other params
[Write(false)] public virtual Instance CurrentInstance { get; set; } = new Instance();
[Write(false)] public virtual ICollection<Instance> Instances { get; set; } = new HashSet<Instance>();
```

and my Instance obj has a FK link to Configurations.

My Dapper request in C# looks like this:

```
var sql = "SELECT Configurations.*, inst.* FROM (SELECT Instances.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Configurations.ID ORDER BY Instances.CreateDate DESC) AS [Row Number] " +
"FROM Configurations INNER JOIN Instances on Instances.ConfigurationID = Configurations.ID) inst " +
"INNER JOIN Configurations ON Configurations.Id=inst.ConfigurationId " +
"WHERE inst.[Row Number] = 1";

return (await connection.QueryAsync<Models.Configuration, Instance, Models.Configuration>(sql,
                (config, instance) =>
                {
                    config.CurrentInstance = instance;
                    //config.Instances.Add(instance);
                    return config;
                }, splitOn: "ID").ConfigureAwait(false)).ToList();
```

I have confirmed that the SQL statement brings back the correct results, but when Dapper tries to bind this to the model, it throws the Access violation that breaks the VS debugger.

The output window in VS says this:
The program '[37088] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 3221225477 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'

When I run the same query but do Instances.Add(instance) in the mapper it breaks the same way. Only when I remove CurrentInstance from the Configuration model does it work, bringing back the single record I need inside the Instances list.

Is there a different/better way to set up these models or the mapper to fill the CurrentInstance portion of the Configuration?

Comment: This sounds like something you should raise an issue for on the Dapper repo. I’m sure they will be very responsive as long as you provide a MVCE

Comment: Dapper is managed code.  There's basically no way a Dapper bug can cause an Access Violation.  This is more likely a Visual Studio issue, unless you can repro it in a simple console application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was going wrong. In my Instance model, I have a property described this way:

```
[Write(false)] public virtual Configuration Configuration { get; set; } = new Configuration();
```

When Dapper creates a new Configuration, it creates a New Instance during construction which creates a new Configuration, etc. The crash didn't say anything about a loop, but it's being stuck in a loop when Dapper tries to instantiate the objects.